# Data Flow Analysis in Roslyn

Tags: c#, roslyn

I have the following code in C#:

```
public class X : IX
{
   public void E(IX d)
   {
        Data dt = new Data();
        dt.Name = ViewState["a"];
        Count(dt);
   }
}
```

And I am using Roslyn to do a few tests concerning data flow analysis.
So, I am passing the first statement (`Data dt = new Data()`) to analyze the data flow and I would like to get as result that there is a flow from the first until third statement.

Is it possible to do this in Rosyln? Get a path that shows the influencing path?

thanks

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at `SemanticModel.AnalyzeDataflow`. It can tell you what variables are read/written/captured/etc in a particular selection.